# How do I call a getter from another getter in Vuex?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Consider a simple Vue blog:
 I'm using Vuex as my datastore and I need to set up two [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html): a `getPost` getter for retrieving a `post` by ID, as well as a `listFeaturedPosts` that returns the first few characters of each featured post. The datastore schema for the featured posts list references the posts by their IDs. These IDs need to be resolved to actual posts for the purposes of showing the excerpts.

**store/state.js**

```
export const state = {
  featuredPosts: [2, 0],
  posts: [
    'Lorem et ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'Lorem et ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'Lorem et ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'Lorem et ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'Lorem et ipsum dolor sit amet',
  ]
}
```

**store/getters.js**

```js
export default getPost = (state) => (postID) => {
  return state.posts[postID]
}

export default listFeaturedPosts = (state, getters) => () => {
  console.log(getters) // {}

  return state.featuredPosts.map(postID => getters.getPost(postID).substring(0, EXCERPT_LENGTH);
}
```

**store/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import state from './state'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
})
```

According to the documentation, the `getters` parameter can be used to access other getters. However, when I try to access `getters` from inside `listFeaturedPosts`, it's empty, and I get an error in the console due to `getters.getPost` being undefined in that context.

How do I call `getPost` as a Vuex getter from inside `listFeaturedPosts` in the example above?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

In VueJS 2.0, you must pass both `state` and `getters`.

Getters are passed to other getters as the **2nd Argument**:

```
export default foo = (state, getters) => {
    return getters.yourGetter
}
```

Official documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access

Answer (score 41):

Pass `getters` as the second argument to access local and non-namespaced getters. For namespaced modules, you should use `rootGetters` (as the **4th** argument, in order to access getters defined within another module):

```
export default foo = (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => {
    return getters.yourGetter === rootGetters['moduleName/getterName']
}
```

Comment: This is useful for people requiring a getter from another vuex module. I just wanted to emphasise that the arguments have to be in the specific order shown in the answer with no arguments omitted, in order for it to work.

Answer (score 29):

Getters receive other getters as **the 2nd argument**

```
getters: {
  doneTodos: state => {
    return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
  },
  doneTodosCount: (state, getters) => {
    return getters.doneTodos.length
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the official docs - https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access

Comment: Thumbs up for:
a) a clear code example
b) link to the proper place in docs

Comment: Is it differnce to write like this instead? getters: {
  doneTodos: state => {
    return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
  },
  doneTodosCount: (state, getters) => {
    return this.getters.doneTodos.length
  }
}

Comment: @Rivo as far as I know you can't do that. If you try you'll get an error like this:

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined"

Answer (score 22):

I Tested without `state` and didn't work. That's why `state` is necessary.

this works:

```
export default foo = (state, getters) => {
    return getters.yourGetter
}
```

this didn't work

```
export default foo = (getters) => {
    return getters.yourGetter
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that it doesn't work in any Vue version. Object destructuring should not be confused with named arguments (see answer in original suggestion to omit 'state'). It is indeed (state, getters)

Comment: In the second example you are naming the `state` object `getters` and ignoring the second argument which would be the actual `getters` object. If you were to introspect `getters` in this example, you would see it was actually your state object.

Answer (score -6):

instead of passing **state**, pass **getters** and then call any other getter you want. Hope it helps.

**In your store/getters.js**

```
export default foo = (getters) => {
   return  getters.anyGetterYouWant
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing Object destructuring with arguments. The first argument to the function is the state, the second is the getters Object. You can name the first argument 'getters', but it will still be the state! You're looking for:

export default foo = (state, getters) => ...

Comment: Or `export default foo = ({ getters }) => {
   return  getters.anyGetterYouWant
}`